# Generating online PDF with Parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, pdf, automation, dynamically-generated

I have a form PDF set up with one field for their name (it is essentially a certificate of a kind). We want this to be automated so for example, www.website.com/file.pdf?Name=Bob and it'll insert 'Bob' into the relevant field. I have tried Javascript at document level but it only works in IE and we need it to work across most browsers especially Chrome and Firefox.

Ideally, we'd like just one PDF to exist, to link that with a parameter in the URL to send to someone and they can download the PDF without filling it in. We're issuing quite a few a day,linking the URL in a separate email (but we're phasing into SQL Server and a 3rd party application to make these emails automated hence the need for this to be automated)

I've tried dozens of websites that fills PDF forms or the like but none result in a single PDF with a URL that can be parsed into the PDF form field. Am I missing any websites that does so or is there an easier way to allow a PDF to do this and host it on my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a server-side script that parses the URL and dynamically generates the PDF form fields with parsed URL parameters.

Here is an example of a ASP.NET generic handler that creates the PDF based on what is submitted in the form. You can instead create PDFs based on values obtained from the URL.
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=315&t=An_ASP_NET_handler_to_create_a_personalized_PDF_form_that_it_that_will_mail_itself_to_an_e_mail_address

You can use any PDF library for this, not necessarily the one used in the article.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnostice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL parameters using **this.path** in the PDF. This property will return the file path of the document, but it will include any parameters that you pass along with it. You can use the path to extract the parameters that you need. So far, this method works on Chrome and IE. Firefox doesn't support filling PDF forms in the browser.